# Как проверить подсеть IP-адресов на вхождение в другую подсеть?

Tags: php, ip, подсети, ip-address

Имеется массив подсетей, например:
192.168.1.240/30
192.168.1.120/28
192.168.2.12/28
127.0.0.4/30

Необходимо проверить, входят ли подсети в другую подсеть, например, в 192.168.1.0/24.
В данном случае 192.168.1.240/30 и 192.168.1.120/28 - входят, 192.168.2.12/28 и 127.0.0.4/30 не входят.

В Интернете довольно много информации о том, как проверить на PHP один IP-адрес на вхождение в подсеть, но сходу придумать/нагуглить, как определить вхождение подсети в подсеть, я не смог.
Была мысль сначала вычислять диапазон большой подсети (с которой будут сравниваться), преобразовать минимальный и максимальный IP-адрес в число с помощью ip2long, потом брать максимальный IP другой подсети, также преобразовать с помощью ip2long, и если максимальный IP входит в диапазон, то подсеть, соответственно, входит в первую подсеть.

Возможно, есть какой-нибудь способ получше? И вообще правильно ли я мыслю? Как выяснить максимальный IP-адрес подсети? И как правильнее реализовать подобную проверку (желательно с небольшим примером кода).

Спасибо.

Comment: Актуально. Есть список подсетей, из которого нужно исключить вложенные диапазоны. Поделитесь примером реализации.

Answer (score 1):

24, 30, 32 - это просто кодированное значение битовой маски, которую нужно применить, и, если результаты совпадут - значит, одна сеть входит в другую.

Comment: А можно чуть подробнее, я не совсем компетентен.  
192.168.1.240/255.255.255.252  
192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0  
Не очень понятно, что значит применить, то есть чтобы и в первом и во втором случае получилось 192.168.1.255?  
Что-то вроде: "если октет маски 255, то не меняем соответствующий октет IP-адреса, если 4-ый *допустим* не 255, то 4 октет IP-адреса меняем на 255"?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> 192.168.1.120/28
> ```

Такой сети **быть не может**. Может быть сеть `192.168.1.112/28` или `192.168.1.120/30`

> ```
> 192.168.2.12/28
> ```

Такой сети тоже не может быть.

---

Чтобы проверить, входит ли подсеть в другую, нужно проверить два условия:

1. Маска этой подсети должна быть меньше, чем у другой подсети.
2. Адрес этой подсети должен входить в другую подсеть.